# How to format textual output with whitespace like tabs or newline?

Tags: python, whitespace, string-formatting

I am somewhat experienced in python, but i have never really had to format my return of a function.

This is my desired format:
[image: desired output]

This is what my output is currently looking like:
[image: actual output]

I have been researching how to use escaped whitespace-chars like `\t`, and I know about `\n` from C++, but I am unsure how to implement these functions.

I have been trying to use `\t` and `\n`, but have not gotten my desired result.

Comment: You wan't it to be centered in the screen?

Comment: Do you want to print to stdout or want the output of the notebook to be centered towards the screen?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals

Comment: A "return" is a piece of useful information. It does not need to be pretty. If you want it to "print" pretty, check https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html

Comment: @jvx8ss not centered, but a print statement with the same format such as, Total words:  top 19 words:  and then list the words and their values as it shows.  I was thinking of making my results into a dictionary but im not sure that would help

Comment: Please post a [example] of the Python-code producing your actual output (so we can reproduce). Also prefer adding output as raw-text instead of images (so we can copy and paste).

Comment: @AnuragReddy I just want my output to look how it does in the desired picture.  Having it say total words: at the top and then list the top 19 as it shows in the desired pic

Comment: @hc_dev.   first i imported collections and re. The format on here isnt good but,  def topWords(book):
    allWords = re.findall(r"[0-9a-zA-Z-']+",book)
    totalWords = len(allWords)
    #print(len(all_words))
    capBook = [i.upper() for i in allWords]
    topBook = collections.Counter(capBook)
    results = topBook.most_common(19)
    for i in results:
        print(i)
    #resultDict = dict(results)
   
    #formatted = "Total Words:"results
    #return formatted

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
words = [
    ('THE', 30062),
    ('AND', 28379),
    ('I', 22307),
    ('THAT', 11924),
]

def print_words(all_words, limit=19):
    totwords = sum([y for x,y in all_words])
    print("Total words:", totwords)
    print()
    print("Top", limit, "words:")

    words = all_words[:limit]
    maxlen = max([len(x) for x, y in words])
    for word, count in words:
        print(f"{word:{maxlen}} {count}")

print_words(words)
```

where

```
print(f"{word:{maxlen}} {count}")
```

means print `word`, and use `maxlen` characters, then print `count`.